# NotImplementedError: PyArray_FromDimsAndDataAndDescr: use PyArray_NewFromDescr

Tags: python, numpy

Input to the function is:

```
MOSFET.z=around(z/10.0,2)

densex = MOSFET.x
densey = MOSFET.y
densez = MOSFET.z

X1=nonuniformgrid(array([min(densex)-1,0.1,min(densex),0.4]));
```

Here is the error I got:

```
out=nonuniformgridmod(argu);
NotImplementedError: PyArray_FromDimsAndDataAndDescr: use PyArray_NewFromDescr.
```

Here is the part of program that give rise to the error.

```
def nonuniformgrid(argu):
    #This is a wrapper for the nonuniformgridmod function
    #so to convert both the argument and the output to numpy arrays
    #I convert the argument in an array
    argarr=array(argu);
    out=nonuniformgridmod(argu);
    # I return a pyarray
    outarr=array(out);
    return outarr;
```

`

what the possible solution to this??

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  In its current state, we can't copy and run your code to reproduce the problem.  For example, you haven't shown how `nonuniformgridmod` is defined.  I suspect it is a C extension that is trying to use an old version of the NumPy C API.

Comment: What is `nonuniformgridmod`?  Looks like it's compiled code from some imported package.  If so, the fix lies with the source, not you